# Android Studio shows error after adding a plugin as guided by a youtube tutorial (the tutorial is 1 year old)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, plugins, module, dependencies

I was learning from a course but it is one year old. so, when I add the third plugin here, it shows an error.

[image]

I am stuck here. Please guide me.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args You need to add that dependency in the *top-level* `build.gradle` file, so you can use the plugin in the *module-level* one. Also make sure you have that `google()` repository - basically just follow the instructions on that page!

Comment: @cactustictacs I have done these things .now it shows an error that it cannot resolve class val .

Comment: You'll have to post a new question, with the error and the code that's causing it - I don't know if you're still talking about Gradle or if this is in your project's code. If this is in your Gradle file, then it sounds like the tutorial is using the Kotlin DSL instead of the usual Groovy language to write the `build.gradle` files. In that case you'd either need to switch to the Kotlin DSL, or rewrite this build file in Groovy. I don't know much about it, but hopefully that will give you something to look into (or some terms to use when asking a new question about it!)